# "This" becomes "window" JavaScript

Tags: javascript, window, this

I'm trying to develop a small game and I have the following problem: I have a pseudo class "Cannon", each Cannon has an array that stores the areas it should guard and an array that stores "intruders" that have entered one of those guarded areas. I created the next function as part of Cannon's prototype:

```
Cannon.prototype.checkIntruderLeftGuardedAreas = function(){
    debugger;
    this.intruders = this.intruders.filter(function(intruder){
        for(var i = 0, l = this.guardedAreas.length; i < l; i ++)
        {
            if(intruder.inInsideGuardedArea(this.guardedAreas[i]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

On the third line I'm trying to filter those intruders that have left the guarded areas, but "this" references to "window" instead of the Cannon objetc that invoked the function.

I also tried this code:

```
var intrudersArray = [];
    for(var i = 0, l = this.guardedAreas.length; i < l; i ++)
        {
            for(var j = 0, k = this.intruders.length; j < k; j++)
            {
               if(this.intruders[j].inInsideGuardedArea(this.guardedAreas[i]))
               {
                   intrudersArray.push(this.intruders[j]);
               }
            }

        }

        this.intruders = intrudersArray;
```

This, according to my logic, does the same thing than the previous block of code: filter the array of intruders. The problem is that on the 6th line where the "if" begins, suddenly "this" references to "window"!. Before reaching that if condition, "this" references to the Cannon object that called the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, scoping can get tricky, you could try the following:

```
Cannon.prototype.checkIntruderLeftGuardedAreas = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.intruders = self.intruders.filter(function(intruder){
        for(var i = 0, l = self.guardedAreas.length; i < l; i ++)
        {
            if(intruder.inInsideGuardedArea(self.guardedAreas[i]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

Notice the line `var self = this;`. It's purpose is saving a reference to your cannon instance to use inside nested callbacks (note how `this` is now `self` inside `filter`) in order to avoid scope issues, it's common to see such stuff in jQuery code.

This practice **ensures** you reference your cannon without the need to track what's going on with `this`, `self` like that is obvious at first glance.

Comment: Hey! That worked perfectly. Thank you. 
I ran the debugger anyway to see what was happening with the code you proposed and I found that "self" reference to my Cannon but "this" turn into "window" on the 4th line where it reads "this.intruders.filter(function(intruder)". Lol. So I still don't understand very well why on the first line "this" is my Cannon but on the 3th it's window. Anyway... thanks again for your help. Now all is working great! :)

Comment: Lolwut, wizards and dragons guard the third line. Fortunately `this` disguised as `self` fools them like Harry Potter's invisible mantle

Answer (score 0):

When you call checkIntruderLeftGuardedAreas, bind the "this" object from the callee.

```
obj.checkIntruderLeftGuardedAreas.bind(this)(arg1, arg2, ..., argn);
```

In JavaScript, this is a context, not the current class.

Example: Define a function that outputs "this"

```
function lol(){console.log(this);}
```

Now call that function

lol();

and you get window.

Furthermore, define a function, and call it in an object:

```
var obj = {  abc: function(){lol(); }}
```

Then

```
obj.abc();
```

will still get you window.
You need

```
var obj = {  abc: function(){lol.bind(this)(); }}
```

And the this context will change to obj, when you call the function

```
obj.abc();
```

You'd probably have to do this:

```
Cannon.prototype.checkIntruderLeftGuardedAreas = function(){
    debugger;
    this.intruders = this.intruders.filter(function(intruder){
        for(var i = 0, l = this.guardedAreas.length; i < l; i ++)
        {
            if(intruder.inInsideGuardedArea(this.guardedAreas[i]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }).bind(this);
}
```

Notice the "bind" on the second-last line.

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for answering. I guess I get what is your point. In fact this helped me to find a different solution from the one that JSelser proposed.
But when I call ".bind(this)" Chrome complains with this: "Uncaught TypeError: this.intruders.filter(...).bind is not a function"
From what I understood of your answer, it should work, but it doesn't. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @Matth Juarez: It's this.intruders.filter.bind(this)(...) , not this.intruders.filter(...).bind(this)